# Суммировать время из двух textview и вывести в новом textview

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть два textview и две кнопки. При нажатии на первую кнопку, открывается окно с выбором времени. Выбираешь время и оно отображается в textview1. Аналогично со второй кнопкой и textview2. Теперь основная задача - просуммировать это время и при нажатии на кнопку Sum вывести в TextView3 сумму времени (textview1+textview2).

Код XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is First Activity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to Second Activity"
        android:id="@+id/btnActTwo"
        android:onClick="onClick">
 
    </Button>
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewTime1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time1" />
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/time1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Time 1"
        android:onClick="setTime"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewTime2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time2" />
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/time2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Time 2"
        android:onClick="setTime2"
        />
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sum" />
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUM"
        android:onClick="onClick2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код Main.java

```
package com.example.myapplication_lab4;
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
 
import java.util.Calendar;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView viewTime1;
    TextView viewTime2;
    TextView sum;
    Button time1;
    Button time2;
    Button btnSum;
    Calendar dateAndTime=Calendar.getInstance();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        viewTime1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewTime1);
        viewTime2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewTime2);
        sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sum);
        time1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time1);
        time2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time2);
        btnSum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSum);
 
    }
    // отображаем диалоговое окно для выбора времени для 1
    public void setTime(View v) {
        new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, t,
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
                .show();
    }
    // отображаем диалоговое окно для выбора времени для 2
    public void setTime2(View v) {
        new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, t2,
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
                .show();
    }
    // установка начального времени для 1
  private void setInitialDateTime() {
 
        viewTime1.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,
                dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                 DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
    }
    // установка начального времени для 2
    private void setInitialDateTime2() {
 
        viewTime2.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,
                dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
    }
    // установка обработчика выбора времени для 1
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            setInitialDateTime();
        }
    };
    // установка обработчика выбора времени для 2
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t2 = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            setInitialDateTime2();
        }
    };
 
 
 
 
//не имеет отношения к задаче
    //Click to go to Activity 2
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button btnActTwo;
        btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
 
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnActTwo) {//call sec act
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
 
    public void onClick2(View view) {
 
    }
}
```

есть идеи как это реализовать? желательно с кодом

Comment: А у тебя какие идеи?)

Comment: Я думаю что FX не поддерживает автоматическую конвертацию типов, хотя тут надо дерзать.

Comment: TextView это всего лишь визуализация, картинка на экране, а не средство хранения информации. Все значения вашего времени вам надо записывать в отдельные переменные (или там массив), потом делайте с ними что хотите: складывайте, форматируйте, выводите на экран ...